# inverse logistic regression with binary covariates

Tags: regression, logistic, hierarchical-bayesian, inverse-prediction

I am currently using a hierarchical Bayesian framework to investigate a problem with both a single binary response variable and binary covariates, $P(Y=1 | X_i=1), i=1,\ldots,n$. Using R/JAGS I can characterize the coefficients, find the odds-ratios, etc. However, I would like to make statements regarding the inverse, $P(X_i=1 | Y=1)$. Any suggestions for an approach or pointers to literature would be appreciated.

Comment: How many covariates are in your model?

Comment: The number of covariants is (potentially) on the order of a few thousand.

Comment: I am curious about how many observations are in the data?

Comment: The observations are effectively limitless. Observations are collected via a system log and collection terminates when the uncertainty in $P(X_i|Y=1)$ converges to some pre-defined level.